# Много мелких таблиц или 1 общая?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Стоит задача хранения и доступа и синхронизации нескольких десятков (может сотен) переменных (строки в общем виде), используемых на разных машинах в локалке. Планирую использовать postgreSQL с механизмами rules / notify для синхронизации кэшированых значений на местах. Набор переменных различен для каждой машины, частично пересекающийся.
Думаю как организовать БД.
1. Хранить все записи в 1 таблице вида (name    VARCHAR(20) primary key,
    val text ), иметь единый notify для всех.
2. Хранить каждую перменную в отдельной таблице (val text ) и отдельный нотифаер для каждой. На каждой машине подписываться на свой набор нотифаеров.

Второй вариант мне нравится больше. Но смущает количество таблиц. Нет ли тут подводных камней?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE vars(stationID INT, varname VARCHAR(n), varvalue TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (stationID, varname))`. А по-хорошему, так ещё и вынести имена в отдельную таблицу-справочник. *Второй вариант мне нравится больше. Но смущает количество таблиц. Нет ли тут подводных камней?* Смущать должна необходимость предоставления клиенту права выполнения DDL.

Comment: Одна таблица и rule использовать не надо. оно срабатывает даже если ничего не изменилось и вы не можете сообщить что изменилось. Вызывайте notify сами в триггере на таблицу, именно в том случае, если изменилось что от важное для клиента. Заодно в полезной нагрузке (payload) в notify можете сообщить клиенту что именно изменилось

Answer (score 0):

А вы уверенны, что для этого вам нужна именно БД ? Судя по всему речь идет о Configuration Management, а в этом случае я бы смотрел на решения типа Consul или Zookeeper.

Comment: postgres выбран потому что клиенты будут Qt based, и там есть все необходимое из коробки. Особых требований по нагрузке и времени отклика нет. Важна кросплатформенность. Так бы по идее лучше какой нибудь Redis подошел.